# UiAutomatorViewer - can't see value in text field

Tags: appium, android-sdk-tools, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I'm making screenshots from my HTC One(M7)- Android 5.02 and can't see value in text field in uiautomatorviewer.I'm using latest version on Android SDK. Getting this error in any app where russian language contained.

```
text="????????? ? ???"
```

Example of code that UiAutomatorViewer generate:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><hierarchy rotation="0"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="ru.fns.billchecker" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="ru.fns.billchecker:id/drawer_layout" class="android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" package="ru.fns.billchecker" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="ru.fns.billchecker" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageButton" package="ru.fns.billchecker" content-desc="Open navigation drawer" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,75][168,243]" /><node index="1" text="????????? ? ???" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="ru.fns.billchecker" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[216,118][734,199]" />
```

[screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSGNM.png)

Comment: an you put us a screenshot? or more details?

Comment: details added. What details do you need?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, if text is not shown because in a language no detectable with  `UiAutomatorViewer`. You can use other location strategies like `className`, `Index` ...

Comment: It not the decision. It means to close eyes to a problem. Why this error doesn't appear on Samsung j3 with Android 5.5.1 ?